# expose RMI server in JBoss?

Tags: java, jboss, rmi

I need to access RMI methods from a client front end.
For different reasons, I have JBoss running on the server side. This makes me thinking of using JBoss to expose the RMI server methods.

I'm kinda new to JBoss, so my question would be: What steps are required in order to make the RMI server methods visible to the client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the how to from JBoss [Steps to Expose Any RMI Interface via HTTP](http://docs.huihoo.com/jboss/online_manual/4.0.1/ch2.chapter.html#d0e7226)